# BPM Detection using Matlab xcorr function

Tags: matlab, audio, audio-processing

**Objective**: Finding the BPM of a short drum loop.

**Approach**:

```
% Step 1: Get audio signal and sample rate
[audio_signal, Fs] = audioread(".\90-bpm.wav"); % Drum loop recorded at 90bpm
audio_signal = audio_signal(:,1); % Only use 1 channel
short_signal = audio_signal(1:1e5,:); % Get short version of sample

% Step 2: Get the audio signal length
audio_length = length(audio_signal);

% Step 3: Create the time vector based on the audio signal length and sampling rate
time = (0:audio_length-1) / Fs; % Used for plotting time axis

% Step 4: Plot the audio signal
plot(time, audio_signal);
xlabel('Time (seconds)');
ylabel('Amplitude');
title('Audio Signal');
grid on;

% Use correlation with a shorter version of the signal
[result, lags] = xcorr(audio_signal, short_signal);

plot(lags/Fs, result); % Normalized lag-axis
xlabel('Lag');
ylabel('xcrorr result');
grid on;

% Find the peaks at their locations
[peaks, locs] = findpeaks(result);
```

**Result**
[image]

**Interpretation**

The result shows two large peaks, where I assume the first one corresponds to the start of both samples (highest point of similarity at lag = 0) and the second largest peak where I assume both samples are most likely repeating itself.

**Questions**

I would like to understand how I can use this result to find the bpm of the drum loop. Would I have to find the time between each peak? How could I determine the bpm using the smaller peaks seen through the result? How does "lag/delay" translate to time?

Thank you in advance!

EDIT: Added plotting lines to show normalization of lag scale.

**FOLLOW-UP**

Based on @Jdip answer I have added the following code:

```
% Use correlation with a shorter version of the signal
[result, lags] = xcorr(audio_signal, short_signal);

plot(lags, result); % Normalized lag-axis
xlabel('Lag');
ylabel('xcrorr result');
grid on;

% Find the peaks at their locations
[pksort, locsort] = findpeaks(result, lags, "SortStr", "descend");
pkpairs= pksort(1:2,:);
locpairs = locsort(:, 1:2);

loc_time = locpairs(:,2)/Fs;
beat_sec = 1/loc_time;
```

**Result**

[image]

```
>> locpairs/Fs

ans =

         0    2.6667

>> loc_time = locpairs(:,2)/Fs;
>> loc_time

loc_time =

    2.6667

>> beat_sec = 1/loc_time;
>> beat_sec

beat_sec =

    0.3750

>> beat_sec * 60

ans =

   22.5000
```

**Original Signal**

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$\texttt{BPM} = \frac{60 \cdot f_s}{\texttt{lag}} $$

Assuming a sampling frequency $f_s=44100$, we’d expect the highest correlation peak to be at $\texttt{lag}\,29400$, which is more or less in agreement with your correlation plot (the x-axis is missing a $\times 10^5$ scaling factor).

Comment: The assumption is correct, the sampling frequency is 44.1kHz. Where does the 60 come from in the equation for the BPM?

Comment: @ChalupaBatmac $f_s/\texttt{lag}$ has units of beats/second, and there are 60 seconds in 1 minute. So you multiply by 60 to get beats/minute

Comment: To give you more detail. Your first correlation peak is at lag (approximately, I can’t see the actual lag) $29000$. So in terms of seconds, that’s $29000/44100 \approx 0.66$ seconds. So the beat repeats every $0.66$ seconds which means there are $1/0.66 = 1.51$ beats per second, or $1.51 \times 60 \approx 90$ beats per minute. Don’t forget to mark the answer if you’re satisfied.

Comment: The formula certainly help translate the locations to time, however it seems that taking the two largest peaks, i.e. the maximum correlation values, which in terms of the signal means when both of these two signals are the "most" similar to one another; the obvious one being at lag = 0, and the less obvious at lag = 117600 (As seen in the picture).

I think the better approach would be looking at the smaller peaks that have equal distance from one another and a similar amount of correlation, not necessarily the highest.

I would love to hear you feedback @Jdip. Thanks!

Comment: Can you post a plot of your signal please?

Comment: The “loop” is about 2.5s long, which is what you find looking at the highest correlation peak. Getting the BPM is going to be more involved (possibly selected transient detection). As a first pass, use xcorr to compute the *autocorrelation* of a single period (one “loop”) and like you said, see if one of the peaks matches 90 bpms using the formula I provided.

Comment: Are you trying to write something that can detect BPM on any drum loop? Or is this just a one-off exercise?

Comment: Certainly seems like the next step, referring to the transient detection. This is a personal project I came up with to challenge my knowledge of DSP, review it and also learn Matlab. The idea is that I should be able to detect any drum loop.

Comment: Ok well the loop is easy enough to detect, it’s just the highest correlation peak, and you’ve done that already (2.66s). The BPM *inside* the loop is trickier.